# Azure app services does it have a certificate store?

Tags: azure, service, certificate, x509

I have a project that communicates with a client server, the client server sends a self-signed certificate and I should trust him in order the continue the connection.

```
 private bool VerifyServerCertificate(LdapConnection ldapConnection, X509Certificate certificate)
 {
    foreach (var cert in CertificateFileNames)
    {
        var certPath = Directory.GetFiles($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}", $"{cert}",System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
           if (File.Exists(certPath.FirstOrDefault()))
           {
               var certToAdd = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath.FirstOrDefault()));
               store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
               X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certToAdd.SubjectName.Name, true);
               if (certs.Count.Equals(0))
               {
                  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                  store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(cert)));
                  store.Close();
               }
           }
        }
        catch
        {
           throw new Exception("Cannot install the certificate.");
        }
    }
    X509Certificate2 certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
    return certificate2.Verify();
 }
```

This works fine but the project needs to be deployed as a Azure app service. So my question is, the app service environment does it have a "Trusted People" storage ?

The method receives de X509certificate from the connection and verify against the trusted people storage so I need to install the certificates before the validation.

Thanks.